# Multiple category archive page

Tags: categories, archives

I am trying to create an archive page that shows posts that are in two categories in the same list.  The listing should only contain posts that belong to BOTH categories, and not posts belonging to one OR the other.

I know this can be done in visual composer / divi but I would rather have this on the archive page itself.

Thanks

Comment: There are 6 types of archive. Author, category, date, tag, custom post type and custom taxonomy. which type of archive do you want to create?

Comment: category archive

Comment: Are you using a custom archive.php template?

Comment: And/or are you adding a new page with it's own permalink, like `example.com/two-categories`?

Comment: Are those two categories predetermined? If yes, then you can create a custom page template with a custom query and use `category__and` parameter to pass those categories ids as an array. `category__and` will make sure posts are in both categories.

Comment: xhynk yes, will be using a page such as example.com/cat-archive.php

@obiPlabon yes, the categories are preset.  I just need something to show all posts that exist in both catA and catB, but not catA OR catB 

:)

Thanks